# SaltStack: Reverse engineering where a file comes from

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, salt-stack, configuration-management

If you look at a host which was set up be SaltStack, then it is sometimes like looking at a binary file with vi.

You have no clue how the config/file was created.

This makes trouble shooting errors hard. Reverse engineering where a file comes from takes too much time.

My goal: Make it easy to find the way from looking at the unix config file on the minion (created by salt) to the source where this configuration came from. Like `$Id$` in svn and cvs.

One idea a friend and I had:

The state [file.managed](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.managed) should (optionally) add the source of the file.

Example:

My sls file contains this:

```
file_foo_bar:
  file.managed:
    - source:
      - salt://foo/bar
```

Then the created file should contain this comment.

```
# Source: salt://foo/bar
```

Of course this is not simple, since there are different ways to put comments into configuration files.

Is this feasible? Or is there a better solution to my goal.

**Update**

Usually I know what I did wrong and can find the root easily. The problem arises if several people work on a state tree.

Comment: It seems difficult to implement. Why don't you just put this comment into your file?

Comment: @ChristopheDrevet-Droguet Why I don't put a comment into the file myself? I am lazy. I would like to automate everything which can be automated. It's like comments in code: sooner or later they are lies, since the code evolves, but the comments don't.

Comment: instead of reading the binary file in vim, why not directly reading the states and just check on the minion if they have the expected result?

Comment: If you really want this feature, I guess this is something you should discuss with devs and others on github. I don't know another solution than putting this comment manually in each file.

Comment: @dahrens I am not looking at binary files. This was a (funny) comparison. My use case looks like this: I am connected to the broken machine via ssh, and I am wondering where this broken configuration comes from. That's why I used the term "reverse engineering". Can you understand what I want? If not, please ask.

Comment: i had already understood. i just used your analogy. i was just wondering why you start debugging on minion side - usually i just read the logs there and check if configuration files look as expected - but the debugging itself takes place in my state tree. i usually know which files comes from where. but we usually deploy one service to one machine, which decreases the amount of files and folders.

Comment: @dahrens ok, you understood me, nice. Yes, usually I know what I did wrong and can find the root easily. The problem arises if several people work on a state tree.

Comment: Ansible has a directive called ansible_managed, I think this is similar for what you looking for. And i am thinking about creating something similar for saltstack. Is that what you looking for ? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#ansible-managed

Comment: @MostafaHussein thank you for the link to the ansible docs. This is exactly what I was looking for. I created a feature request: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/37068

Comment: What about using a pillar for this until we can figure it out either from salt team or contributing ? I will be gald to help :D

Comment: @MostafaHussein I don't understand how you can use a pillar for this.

Comment: I have added an example of how to make use of pillar but still uncomplete solution as i need to find a way to access the event bus in order to get the name of the user who executed the state https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/37068#issuecomment-254477571

Comment: @guettli, I have updated my answer again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a starting point where you can get the date and time of the modified file when its managed by Salt by using [Salt Pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/pillar.html).

Lets call our variable `salt_managed`. Create a pillar file like the following:

```
{% set managed_text = 'Salt managed: File modified on ' + salt.cmd.run('date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"') %}

salt_managed: {{ managed_text | yaml_dquote }}
```

Then on the minion when you call the pillar you will get the following result:

```
$ salt-call pillar.get salt_managed
local:
    Salt managed: File modified on 2016-10-18 11:12:40
```

And you can use this by adding it on the top of your config files for example like this:

```
{{ pillar.get('salt_managed') }}
```

Update:

I found a work around that might be useful for someone. Lets say we have a multiple states that could modify the same file. How can we know that State X is the responsible for modifying that file ? by doing the following steps:

1-  I have created a state like this one:

```
Create a File:
  file.managed:
    - name: /path/to/foofile
    - source: salt://statedir/barfile
Add file header:
  file.prepend:
    - name: /path/to/foofile
    - text: "This file was managed by using this salt state {{ sls }}"
```

The contents of barfile is:

```
This is a new file
```

2- Call the state from the minion and this will be the result:

```
$ salt-call state.sls statedir.test
local:
----------
          ID: Create a File
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /path/to/foofile
      Result: True
     Comment: File /path/to/foofile updated
     Started: 07:50:45.254994
    Duration: 1034.585 ms
     Changes:   
              ----------
              diff:
                  New file
              mode:
                  0644
----------
          ID: Add file header
    Function: file.prepend
        Name: /path/to/foofile
      Result: True
     Comment: Prepended 1 lines
     Started: 07:50:46.289766
    Duration: 3.69 ms
     Changes:   
              ----------
              diff:
                  ---  
                  +++  
                  @@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
                  +This file was managed by using this salt state statedir.test
                   This is a new file

Summary for local
------------
Succeeded: 2 (changed=2)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     2
```

Currently the content of `foofile` is:

```
This file was managed by using this salt state statedir.test
This is a new file
```